# Styling HTML to be displayed in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, css, styles

I'm trying to produce an HTML document which will render at least partway passably in Excel.

The problem is that I can't get background colours to show up.

Code:

```
#header {
     background:Blue;
     color:white;
     font-family: Arial;
     text-align:center;
     padding:1px;
     }

<div id = "header">
<H1>HeaderName</H1>
</div>
```

The problem is that the font is correctly set as white, Arial, Centered, but the background is not set. (Leading, in this case, to white on white)

Why is it setting the font, but not the background?

Comment: Try `#0000ff`or `#4696E6` instead of `Blue`

Comment: It seems that Excel can only read HTML style infor inline, and only from <td> elements. Although this doesn't really explain why it's styling the font but not the background.